# RT2800USB wireless adapter stops scanning

Tags: drivers, usb, wifi

I have a Linux machine, and I'll switch between using an RTL8187 based card, and a RT2800USB based card (the cards are both USB dongles by the same manufacturer).

I've loaded the drivers for both cards:

```
modprobe rtl8187
modprobe rt2800usb
```

I can run an iwlist scan against the RTL8187 card until I'm blue in the face, but after a few minutes of doing the same with the RT2800USB card, it stops working, and displays the following:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     No scan results
```

What can I do to get the card to work 100%?